# Command in atom terminal giving different results than command prompt

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I'm attempting to create a file from my an embedded terminal in my text editor, Atom. The terminal is from the package "platformio-ide-terminal"

When I run a command to create a file in windows command prompt, I am able to create a file without issue, however, when I run the exact same code in my terminal thats embedded in atom it doesn't work.

The command that I'm running is `type nul > lecture3.md` since I'm trying to create a markdown file. As previously mentioned, this works fine in command prompt, but when I run it in my terminal in atom it seems to interpret the command like I'm trying to enter a folder called "nul", which obviously doesn't exist. The error that's being displayed is as follows:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ type nul > lecture3.md
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pathtocurrentfolder\nul:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I would like to know why this error is happening from my terminal in atom, and not in command prompt, and how I can rectify this issue.

Comment: Your embedded terminal is running PowerShell, whereas you're trying to run a `cmd.exe` command. The PowerShell equivalent of the latter is `$null > lecture3.md`. Either reconfigure Atom to use `cmd.exe` as the embedded terminal's shell or, preferably, start using PowerShell commands.

Comment: When I create a file using this, its initialized having 2 bytes, instead of 0. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Good point - that happens in _Windows PowerShell_ (but not in PowerShell _Core_), where `>` defaults to UTF-16LE encoded files; what you're seeing is that encoding's BOM. Try `New-Item -Type File lecture3.md`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exception working on visual code. Most IDE have costume handling exceptions. Probably the IDE is trying to check if nul exist even thou the terminal is passing the command just fine.

I received a similar message on Visual Code for  `type nul > "yourfile.txt"`:

```
> type : Cannot find path 'C:\nul' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ type nul > "yourfile.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\nul:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Even that I got the error the command worked and the file was created. You could check the folder to confirm the creation of the file from the terminal inside de IDE with the `dir` command if your working directory is set on the directory where you created the file.